# How do you bind a function to another function 'event status' in PHP

Tags: php, debugging, logging, binding

To ease up the debuging for my class(es) I want to bind a function to the status of other function events. The current set-up I have, is similair to following the code:

```
class config {

    function __construct($file) {

        $this->functions = array(); // The array with function run/succes information

        if (!empty($file)) {
            $this->checkFile($file);
        }
    }

    public function checkFile($file) {
         $this->functionStatus('run',true);

         if (file_exists($file)) {

            $this->functionStatus('succes',true);
            return true; 
        } else {
            $this->functionStatus('succes',true);
            return false;
        }
     }

    /* Simplified functionStatus function */
    private function functionStatus($name,$value) {

        /* - validations removed -*/

        // Get parent function name
        $callers = debug_backtrace();
        $function = $callers[1]['function'];

         /* - validations removed -*/


        $this->functions[$function][$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

An example of the principle in use:

```
$config = new config('example.ini');
print var_dump($config->functions);
/* Results in:
array(1) { 
    ["checkFile"]=> array(2) { 
        ["run"]=> bool(true) 
        ["succes"]=> bool(true) 
    } 
} 
*/
```

While this set-up works fine. I would like to improve it by removing the manually placed `$this->functionStatus('run',true)` function everytime I create a function to keep the code a bit cleaner and prevent assuming a function isn't run because someone forgat defining the functionStatus at top of the function. Same goes for the definitions at the return events.

*Note, the best solution would also support this binding with other classes
Is there any way to accomplish this 'event binding' with PHP ?

Comment: `private function functionStatus($name = 'run', $value = true) {`

Comment: If you want to use this with other classes, use inheritance; or create a completely separate logging class and use composition, or use a logger library like log4php or Monolog

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `__call` magic method. Change all your public functios to private methods, and add a prefix to the name, e.g.

```
private function internal_checkFile($file) {
    ...
}
```

Then add the magic method:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    $this->functionStatus('run', true);
    return call_user_func_array(array($this, "internal_$name"), $arguments);
}
```